# Is it possible (and safe) to stop the Windows Easy Transfer in mid-transfer?

Tags: windows-easy-transfer

I'm writing a 26GB WET file to a new Windows 7 PC and it's going to take 13h.

There's no "stop" button, so I'd have to click the [x] to close it.

Is that safe?

*Clarification:* will closing it just "undo" the changes or at least allow me to complete the transfer later as if I had never stopped it?

Comment: well i really think it's not safe to close any file transfer if the file transfer process is transferring important files

Answer (score 0):

It was stuck at completion estimate of 14h 7 min, for an hour.
So I clicked the "x" and it offered to close and it offered to close WET. (So I didn't have to Kill the process)

BTW, lots of reports out there of WET stalling.

Answer (score 0):

"Safe" is ambiguous here. Do you want to use the file that has been created? You won't be able to, but it won't break your computer.

*Edit

Closing it will force you to start from scratch.